# Cannot retrieve json data from an url with python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve a json data with below code. json data is shown just fine on chrome/inspect/preview but the data retrieved is error message.

The main url is 'https://www.dsmartgo.com.tr/film/aksiyon-macera' and the purpose is to get the movie name and image url. It seems the site gets the date from https://service-dsmart.erstream.com/api/GetFilteredVideos as json.

Tried to reach the source code with bs4 as another option but infos are hidden in the source.

How can I get the real json data that can be shown in chrome/inspect/preview instead of the error message?

Thanks in advance.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
html_content = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text
page_content = json.loads(html_content)
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send a `POST` request with a valid `payload`. No need for `bs4` as there's no `HTML` to parse.

Here's how:

```
import requests


headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "Host": "service-dsmart.erstream.com",
    "Origin": "https://www.dsmartgo.com.tr",
    "Referer": "https://www.dsmartgo.com.tr/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36",
}

content_id_url = "https://ues.ercdn.com/ues/client/get_trending_contents/?publicKey=8hopodesqeosh00atuv36uooh452i8t0"
payload = {"ids": [i['contentID'] for i in requests.post(content_id_url).json()['result']]}


response = requests.post(
    "https://service-dsmart.erstream.com/api/GetItemsByIds",
    json=payload,
    headers=headers,
).json()

for movie in response:
    print(movie['Name'])
```

Output:

```
Terminatör: Kara Kader
Sen Çal Kapımı 2020 10 07
Çukur - 2020 10 05
Derin Sular
Masumlar Apartmanı 2020 10 06
2036: Kökeni Bilinmeyen
Düşmanım
Eşkiya Dünyaya Hükümdar Olmaz - 2020 10 06
Ajanlar İş Başında
Menajerimi Ara 2020 10 06
Kingsman: Gizli Servis
Buz Devri: Büyük Çarpışma
Tavşan Jojo
Kırmızı Oda 2020 10 02
Yürüyen Ev : Zeynep - Özgür Karaman
Yıldızlara Doğru
Üç Telli Tutku / Emre Dayıoğlu
Asfaltın Kralları
Mucize Doktor - 2020 10 08
Yasak Elma - 2020 10 05
Arıza 2020 10 04
Kırmızı Oda 2020 10 09
Sefirin Kızı 2020 09 28
Uyanış: Büyük Selçuklu 2020 10 05
Gölün Fısıltısı / Doğan Anapa
Kuruluş Osman 2020 10 07
Bay Yanlış 2020 10 02
Sen Çal Kapımı 2020 09 30
Tepki
Salgın
Ramo 2020 10 09
Skandal
Ramo 2020 10 02
Kurye
Körfez Rüzgarı / Beste Önkol
Travma Merkezi
Kurşun Geçirmez
Garfield
Seninle Bir Ömür
Hekimoğlu 18. Bölüm
Rojo
Dişi Şahin
Kanunun Kuvveti
Yeni Hayat 5. Bölüm
Mucize Doktor - 2020 10 01
Masumlar Apartmanı 2020 09 29
Lucy Gökyüzünde
Hekimoğlu 20. Bölüm
Gizemli Kadın
Kuşatma
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. And how do you get the proper payloads?

Comment: From the Developer Tool - Network and at the bottom of the request made to the above url there's payload. By the way, if you find the answer useful do accept it.

Comment: Ok but how can I get the ids in a python way? I need the scrap the ids also, but from which source? Can you please also help me out with that?

Comment: @sume I've udpated the answer.

Comment: One more question: Can you also explain me how you reached the content_id_url? in dev tools most probably but how? :)